# How can you position an element or image to stand outside its containing layer in photoshop?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop

I have the following need, please see below:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/4lgm8iiqn/c1dcfaed/]

The width of the layer is 370 px and the height is 40

**Image A**: the green box is a layer with a gradient. The pink box is a shape inside the gradient layer.

**Image B**: The way I need it to be: even though the shape is positioned inside the layer, I need it to have an absolute positioning in relation to its container.

How do I achieve this?